# ASP.NET Core 6 named connection string not found

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

I am using .NET 6 and Entity Framework Core 6 in a new ASP.NET Core MVC web app. I have my connection string set in user-secrets. I was able to perform a

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold Name=ConnectionStrings:someconn
```

without any trouble. My model context was created. Now I want to do a simple query, but the builder in `program.cs` is complaining about not finding the connection.

Here I create a builder

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var currentDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
var environmentName = builder.Environment.EnvironmentName;

builder.Configuration
    .SetBasePath(currentDirectory)
    .AddUserSecrets<Program>()
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStrings:someconn ");
```

Here I place this code inside program.cs, and just before app.Run.

```
using (var ctx = new ModelContext())
{
    List<SomeModel> pd = ctx.SomeModel
        .Where(p => p.Id == "12345").ToList();

}

app.Run();
```

Error

> A named connection string was used, but the name 'ConnectionStrings:someconn' was not found in the application's configuration

Comment: please post the appsettings file containing the connection string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a sample for reading a connection string from appsettings.json. (for simplicity I've used a sample for sqlite, which shouldn't affect they general way of reading the string.)

Hope this helps.

appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Information"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "someconn": "Data Source=some.sqlite"
  }
}
```

and the in Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("someconn")
```

A reason could be that the `appsettings.json` isn't found. Maybe check if this part of the code is needed or execute it after reading the connection string.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("someconn")


var currentDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
var environmentName = builder.Environment.EnvironmentName;

builder.Configuration
    .SetBasePath(currentDirectory)//check if this is necessary
    .AddUserSecrets<Program>()
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

Comment: The important detail here is that `.GetConnectionString("key")` looks for "ConnectionStrings" in appsetings.json, and gets the next down-one-level item based on the key. If your appsettings.json has `"ConnectionStrings": {"key":"value"}` then you'll get "value" from `.GetConnectionString("key")`

Answer (score 0):

Change below code

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStrings:someconn ");
```

to

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("someconn");
```

It works in my local, you can try it. Also note that there is an extra space in your code.

[image]

Comment: That wasn't it. My connection fragment in my question was just an example. Thanks.